# How to animate PieChart sector on highlight for the Charts library?

Tags: ios-charts

When I highlight a sector in a PieChartView, the sector changes to the dataSet's highlightColor + the selectionShift. However this happens immediately and I'd like to animate this transition.

Currently the only animate function I see is for ChartViewBase, which animates the entire chart (which is what I do not want).

Is there anyway to only animate a single (selected) sector?

I have the following code as a starting point, but I can't apply transform to the entry nor the highlight

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
    let translation1 = CGAffineTransform(scaleX: 1.5, y: 1.5)
    let translation2 = CGAffineTransform(translationX: 1.0, y: 1.0)
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: { in
        entry.transform = translation1
    }) { didComplete in
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.4, animations: {
            entry.transform = translation2
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you check my ans of animation ?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried below property for animation selected value ?

```
self.pieChart.highlightPerTapEnabled = true
```

Check this may be help to animate while highlighted.